# Adding static content "pages" to Knockout single page app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, single-page-application

I've built a route planning single page app which relies heavily on entering details which get displayed on a Google map. The entire thing was originally written in only Javascript but now has an ASP.NET MVC server side to facillitate saving, logging in, etc. However, I'm struggling with an effective way to show static content like help and terms and conditions. Right now I have all of that content in the main HTML and use model bindings on booleans to show/hide the content in a popup. I feel this has a couple of problems:

1. SEO - Since all the content is on one page and usually hidden and not specifically accessible it feels like search engines wouldn't be able to find/optimize the content
2. Bloated models - The additional booleans feel more "view" than "model" and since each content needs a new property and show logic it doesn't seem DRY.

What are some patterns and frameworks to help mitigate these issues? Any solution that also helps communicate with the server via JSON is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

These additional booleans to control what to show are in my opinion perfectly fine, they're neither `view` nor `model`, they are `View Model`. After all, knockoutjs follows the `MVVM` pattern.

If you want to keep you view models from being bloated you could use one observable which determines what template you want to show, which in a way also could control if the popup should be shown or not, in pseude code:

html:

```
<script type="text/html" id="terms"> ... </script>

<script type="text/html" id="conditions"> ... </script>

<script type="text/html" id="help"> ... 
    <button data-bind="click: show(undefined)"> close </button>
</script>

<button data-bind="click: show('help')"> Help </button
<div id="popup" data-bind="if: showActive">
<!-- ko template: showActive -->
<!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

javascript:

```
var viewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.showActive = ko.observable();

    self.show = function(showWhat){
        self.showActive(showWhat);
    }
}
ko.applyBinding(new viewModel()) ;
```

About the SEO part, [google](http://www.google.com/search?q=knockoutjs+template+seo) has plenty of articles about that.